# A puzzling stained glass window

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story

On a recent trip to Europe, I visited a beautiful gothic abbey. Walking up the dark aisle between old wooden pews, the air heavy with the odour of incense, I could only marvel at the beautiful stained glass windows illuminating parts of the massive stone church with their vibrant light, and especially at the huge square window shining in the darkness above the entrance.

Legend has it that the abbott who designed the abbey’s stained glass was a puzzler, and that he left a little message in this particular window, elucidating the philosophy and religion behind his glass art.

**Can you explain the meaning of this stained glass window?**

---

*The following is a photograph of the stained glass window above the entrance of the church:*

[image: Window]

---

**Hint:**

> This square window is divided into little pieces. I wonder if the way they are *connected* is important...?

---

<sub>If the perspective or light bloom in my 'photograph' bothers you, there is a simple schematic version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X46i.png) which is all you need to solve this simple puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It spells:

> John 1:5. [A bible verse:](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201%3A5&version=NIV) "The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it."

> [image]

Comment: Nice work! +1. Green checkmark coming shortly.